# Being told I cannot mark a comment more then once when upvoting for the first time

Tags: bug, comments

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621238/text-fields-do-not-work-in-safari) question a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621238/text-fields-do-not-work-in-safari#comment88252360_50621238) was left as a possible duplicate. When I went to upvote this comment it showed me the error message that I couldn't upvote the comment like below.
[image]

However, as you can see from the below image, I had not marked the comment at all, and it was on 0 votes at that time.

[image]

So although I marked the comment no vote was shown, but when I try and mark the comment again, it says that I have already voted it.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Did you flag it as duplicate before you tried to upvote the comment?

Comment: @rene yes, does that automatically upvote the comment?

Comment: It does when I close vote as a duplicate. It has been a while that I could only flag for duplicates so I don't remember how it worked back then. Refreshing the page after you raised a duplicate flag might help in confirming the behavior. Comment votes are not send over the websocket so you won't see updates after you clicked a more comments link (when available) or did a full refresh.

Comment: I can verify that flagging also upvotes the duplicate comment.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere, or is it just something known. If its not could it be left as an answer so that other users are able to know and won't have the same confusion

Comment: There have been a number of questions about the behavior; e.g. [Is voting up a duplicate comment the same thing as marking it as a duplicate?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312269) & [Vote to close a question automatically upvotes comment that disagrees](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340833) popped up in a quick search.

Comment: The probable cause is that flagging the post as the same dupe votes the relevant up, but it isn't made visible without a page reload. This is a different problem as was written in the dupe candidate.